# Qt QGridLayout identical width and height for elements,

Tags: qt

I am trying out QT to rework a WPF project. I want to use a QGridLayout for laying out buttons, each 64x64 px in dimension. However, the grid does not seem to respect these dimensions, I'm sure 64x64 is not that small. Also, there is a huge gap between the elements. How could I more tightly pack these buttons and make them all be uniformally 64 by 64 px? Preferrably even limit column and row count to 4 and window_height/64

Code:

```
#include "productbuttongrid.h"

#include <QPushButton>

ProductButtonGrid::ProductButtonGrid(QWidget *parent): QGridLayout(parent)
{

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Toode", parent);
    button->setFixedSize(64,64);

    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Toode2", parent);
    button2->setFixedSize(64,64);

    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Toode2", parent);
    button3->setFixedSize(64,64);
    QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Toode2", parent);
    button4->setFixedSize(64,64);
    QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Toode2", parent);
    button5->setFixedSize(64,64);

    this->addWidget(button,0,0);
    this->addWidget(button2,0,1);
    this->addWidget(button3,0,2);
    this->addWidget(button4,0,3);
    this->addWidget(button5,1,0);

}
```

And what this outputs, instead of the 64x64 buttons: They also seem a bit too small to be 64x64

[image]

Comment: Note: you call `button2->setFixedSize(64,64);` four times.  Probably not what you intended.

Comment: @G.M.correct. Edited the Q with the correct code, and new output.

Comment: @RandoHinn 
What is the problem with the output? I see that the buttons are the right size.

Comment: Spacing. I want a tight grid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the buttons tightly spaced then you need to provide the `QGridLayout` with some means of using any extra space it's given.

The easiest way in this instance would simply be to create a dummy row and column below and to the right of the buttons and allow them to stretch.  So, simply add...

```
setRowStretch(rowCount(), 1);
setColumnStretch(columnCount(), 1);
```

at the end of your `ProductButtonGrid` constructor.

If you want to have the button grid aligned centrally then arrange to have stretchable `extra' rows/columns above, below and left, right of the buttons.

You might also wish to remove the usual inter-item spacing using [`QGridLayout::setSpacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setSpacing).